# PySimpleGUI: Font rendering issue

Tags: fonts, pysimplegui

I'm using a font on my dev machine, however when I bundle the application as an exe and deploy it on another machine which does not have that font installed, the font rendering shifts to default. Is there a way I can bundle the font with the exe and have PySimpleGUI use that instead of trying to locate the font in the system (implying it needs to be installed first)? Any workaround for this?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg    
sg.set_options(font=['Inder',10])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use library `pyglet` to add font files, and use option `--add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>` of `PyInstaller` to bundle the font files.

> Additional non-binary files or folders to be added to the executable. The path separator is platform specific, `os.pathsep` (which is `;` on Windows and `:` on most unix systems) is used. This option can be used multiple times.

[Update] There's issue to work with tkinter.filedialog module. Set COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED mode before your code.

Demo code

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.libs.win32 import constants
import PySimpleGUI as sg


constants.COINIT_MULTITHREADED = 0x2  # 0x2 = COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED

# pyglet.font.add_file(r".\MerryChristmasFlake.ttf")
# pyglet.font.add_file(r".\MerryChristmasStar.ttf")

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
font1 = ("Merry Christmas Flake", 40)
font2 = ("Merry Christmas Star", 40)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Merry Christmas Flake", font=font1)],
    [sg.Text("Merry Christmas Star",  font=font2)],
    [sg.Input(), sg.FolderBrowse()],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

[image]

After two remark lines unmarked,
[image]

Note: font file downloaded from https://www.1001freefonts.com/d/17982/merry-christmas.zip, and put those two font files to same path as main script.